# Get the full path of a node, after get it with an XPath query in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

i have the next instruction, in JavaScript:

```
var firstScene = document.evaluate('//Scene', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
```

so my question is how to get the full path of the node `firstscene`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this [getXPath() function](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4349):

```
  function getXPath(node, path) {
    path = path || [];
    if(node.parentNode) {
      path = getXPath(node.parentNode, path);
    }

    if(node.previousSibling) {
      var count = 1;
      var sibling = node.previousSibling
      do {
        if(sibling.nodeType == 1 && sibling.nodeName == node.nodeName) {count++;}
        sibling = sibling.previousSibling;
      } while(sibling);
      if(count == 1) {count = null;}
    } else if(node.nextSibling) {
      var sibling = node.nextSibling;
      do {
        if(sibling.nodeType == 1 && sibling.nodeName == node.nodeName) {
          var count = 1;
          sibling = null;
        } else {
          var count = null;
          sibling = sibling.previousSibling;
        }
      } while(sibling);
    }

    if(node.nodeType == 1) {
      path.push(node.nodeName.toLowerCase() + (node.id ? "[@id='"+node.id+"']" : count > 0 ? "["+count+"]" : ''));
    }
    return path;
  };
```

pass the DOM ojbect obtained from `firstScene.iterateNext()` to the `getXPath()` method and it will return an array with all of the XPATH steps.

You can then use the array `join()` method to return a full XPATH expression:

```
getXPath(firstScene.iterateNext()).join("/");
```

Comment: it doesn't work, where you get all that properties? i debug the program and a XpathResult doesn't have definition for any of the things that you use, nodeType, nextSibling, previousSibling....The only thing that an iterator of XpathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE has is a method to move to the next result node iterateNext() and properties to access to the inner value.

Comment: Sorry about that. I tested with the results of `document.getElementById`. I'll look and see if I can get it to evaluate properly with the results of the XPATH evaluation.

Comment: Looks like the `getXPath()` method expects a DOM Object and the result of the XPATH expression is not, but you can obtain it from the `iterateNext()` method.  I have corrected my answer with something that worked for me.

Comment: well i test it and with iterateNext neither work, however using the property singleNodeValue that return an HTMLElement your function works!!!, thanks for the help....now i have just one little problem left....in some pages i have different frames so the contextNode (the second argument from evaluate) it's not document, so the query fails...i'm searching how to overcome that issue.