# Custom tag not considered HTMLelement/parent in webbrowser DOM c#

Tags: c#, dom, xpath, webbrowser-control

I am working on a XPATH generator (using absolute paths). 
 The idea is that I have a function where you pass a HTMLElement (that is found in the webbrowser) and it will return the XPATH like:

**/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/a**

The function to generate the xpath looks something like this:

```
HTMLElement node=...;
while (node != null)
     {
       int i = FindElementIndex(node); //find the index of our current node in the parent elements
       if(i==1)
          xpath.Insert(0, "/" + node.TagName.ToLower());
       else
          xpath.Insert(0, "/" + node.TagName.ToLower() + "[" + i+ "]");
       node = node.Parent;
    }
```

The idea is this:

a)take the element

b)find the index position of element in element.parent

c)append xpath

The problem appears when the parent is a custom html code like "`<layer>`"
 Example:

```
<html>
  <body>
     <div>
        <layer>
           <a href="http://site.com">aaa</a>
        </layer>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If our HTMLElement is `<a href="http://site.com">aaa</a>` and we call
 ourelement.Parent it will return the DIV element and **NOT** the  element

So instead of having:
**/html/body/div/layer/a**

We will have (which is incorrect)
**/html/body/div/a**

How can this be solved? Really hope someone can help figure this out.

**EDIT 1:** Just for testing purposes I implemented the function from [Get the full path of a node, after get it with an XPath query in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071920/get-the-full-path-of-a-node-after-get-it-with-an-xpath-query-in-javascript)

The results were that if the page that contained a "custom" tag (like `<layer>`) AND if the page was opened in firefox, the xpath was showed correctly.

If the page was opened in Internet Explorer (like webbrowser is) the `<layer>` was not included as a parent.

So the issue is with internet explorer not "parsing" the dom correctly. What is the solution? What function can help create xpath for cases like this (if using webbrowser htmlelement).

Comment: You may be interested in this XSLT solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746299/generate-get-xpath-from-xml-node-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question; but have considered using http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ to load the HTML.  It will not have the problem of ignoring the  element.

Comment: I am using the htmlagilitypack, but I have a dom selector (similar to firebug) that selects a htmlelement from the webbrowser. I than need to get the htmlnode (htmlagilitypack node) that corresponds to the htmlelement selected. I first tried comparing outerhtml of the element, but the dom outerhtml of the webbrowser is sometimes (it formats the text) different than the htmlagilitypack outerhtml. That's why I need to get the XPATH of the HTMLElement, so I can find the Htmlagilitypack HTMLNode. Hope it makes sense